# How do I pass a dynamic array of Classes to a vararg?

Tags: java

I want to create a dynamic array of Classes to pass to a vararg.  Is this possible?  If not, what's the best way to dynamically create a normal array of Classes?  The code below gives the error that follows.

Code -

```
private void validate(Validator vt, Object form, BindingResult errors, Class<?>... c){
    vt.validate(form, c);   
}

private void validate(Type type, BindingResult errors){         

Validator vt = new Validator();
List groups = new ArrayList();

   if(form.isAvailable()){      
          groups.add(Available.class);
   }
       if(form.isNotAvailable()){
          groups.add(NotAvailable.class);
   }    
   if(groups.size()>0){
      validate(vt, form, errors, groups.toArray());
   }      
}
```

Error -

```
The method validate(Validator, Object, BindingResult, Class<?>...) is not applicable for the arguments (Validator, Field, BindingResult, Object[])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try parameterizing your List and ArrayList as

> List< Class< ? > > groups = new
>   ArrayList< Class< ? > >();

also, when converting to array, use:

> groups.toArray( new Class[
>   groups.size() ] );

Answer (score 2):

The array returned by [`List.toArray()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28%29) is an Object[], which can't be cast to a Class[]. Try using the [`List.toArray(T[])`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29) like this instead: `groups.toArray(new Class<?>[groups.size()])`, that should return the type of array you're looking for.

Comment: @Henrick-Gustafsson - This alone did not resolve the issue, but combined with a parameterized instantiation like this - List<Class<?>> groups = new ArrayList<Class<?>>(); - solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

just do this

```
private void validate(ValidationTool vt, Object form, BindingResult errors, Class[] c){
    vt.validate(form, c);   
}
```

Comment: @yasser-souri That would fix the issue in this location but I have other locations that call for a vararg list of Classes.